# html colspan rowspan

Tags: html, html-table

I work with html table, colspan and rowspan. I want to create table like this:

```
._______________________.
|       |       |       |
|______ |_______|_______|
|___|___|       |___|___|
|       |_______|       |      
|_______|___|___|_______|
```

But can't find solution! Please help!

Comment: I tried create

3 cells with colspan2 rowspan2
cell cell ,cell with colpan2rowspan2, cell cell
cell with colspan2 rowspan2 ,cell cell, cell with colspan2 rowspan2

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes, examine my example to see how it's done. When you a `<td>` has a `colspan` or `rowspan` it is expanded and the next `<td>` that is meant to be in that position is skipped (see the last `<tr>` only has 2 `<td>`s).

[image: table]

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/tAsbE/)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: yeah! I must use /br tag :)

Comment: Thank you! It's work!
I must use /br, this is why my table don/t work!

Comment: Good to hear :) don't forget to accept the answer by hitting the tick.

Answer (score 0):

Make a table with four rows, and cells in the rows with these settings:

```
colspan 6

none
none
colspan 2, rowspan 2
none
none

colspan 2, rowspan 2
colspan 2, rowspan 2

none
none
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=6>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan=2 rowspan=2>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2 rowspan=2>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan=2 rowspan=2>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdZK4/3/)