# Don't work colspan or rowspan in table html

Tags: html, html-table

I don't span cells `cell1_1` and  `cell1_2`. When I'm using  `colspan="2"` at `#cell1_1` it don't work. My [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Erush/xcwk3d09/) 
I try use [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571556/html-colspan-rowspan?answertab=votes#tab-top) at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/tAsbE/)
,but don't work tag `br` when I use rowspan. 

I don't understand how working skipping cells?

But can't find solution! Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `colspan="2"` works fine. The problem is that there is no other cell that's *only* in column #2. So the browser makes column 2 very small.

Try adding this row at the end and you'll see it start working:

```
<tr class="row10">
  <td>10_1</td>
  <td>10_2</td>
  <td>10_3</td>
  <td>10_4</td>
  <td>10_5</td>
  <td>10_6</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I want ask you question: When need use colspan and rowspan cells in the table I must zero row and col insert in a table? How would you make this table? I'll made like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Erush/71d9kj58/3/). It's ok?